# Does a Hibernate/OpenJPA/EclipseLink driver exist for Hive or Impala and is there an obstacle to creating one?

Tags: hibernate, hive, eclipselink, openjpa, impala

My searches indicate that there do not exist any Hibernate/OpenJPA/EclipseLink drivers for Hive or Impala. One obstacle is that databases like Hive do not implement update commands in standard mode since ORC and Parquet files are CRD-only (create, read, delete, no update). Also uniqueness, autoincrement, joining and some other operations may be difficult or impossible. However, would it be possible to implement such drivers for the HQL/SQL commands implemented by Hive and Impala without any bigger obstacles/problems?
*Edit*: I'm actually looking for drivers supporting as many SQL features as possible since Hive and Impala support large subsets of SQL. I'm not looking for a NoSQL driver.

Comment: EclipseLink has generic support for NoSql: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/NoSQL and others have adapted it for other platforms: https://blogs.oracle.com/NoSQL/entry/eclipselink_jpa_and_oracle_nosql

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question is right for SO, but here's the answer anyway:

There are no obstacles/problems. Hibernate already has support for some NoSQL datastores as part of the [OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) project (currently supports mongo, Neo4J and EhCache).

You can definitely contribute new dialects to the OGM project.